# Is it possible to use use exams2pdf and to obtain the solution of the exact same version generated with exams2nops?

Tags: r-exams

When generating exams using the function `exams2nops` we randomly generate data for each of the produced exams (let's say 5 different versions). We would like to use the exact same version of each exam to produce the solutions version (using `exams2pdf`). Is it possible to create the solution version right on the go when generating exams with the `exams2nops`? By exact same version I mean, the same order of the multiple-choice answers and the same wrong values (using the marvelous `num_to_schoice` function). We save the `.rds` objects used on each exercise, allowing us to obtain import them when generating solutions, however, the wrong options and order are different since it is random. Should we also save a specific seed in the `.rds` object? Inside each exercise, we have several random generated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the same random seed prior to calling `exams2pdf()` and `exams2nops()` you should get the same random versions of the exercises.

Illustration: `n = 2` version of an `exm` with 3 exercises.

```
library("exams")
exm <- c("capitals.Rmd", "deriv2.Rmd", "tstat2.Rmd")
set.seed(1)
exm1 <- exams2pdf(exm, n = 2)
set.seed(1)
exm2 <- exams2nops(exm, n = 2)
```

Compare the question list of all three exercises in the second random version of the exams:

```
all.equal(exm1[[2]][[1]]$questionlist, exm2[[2]][[1]]$questionlist)
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(exm1[[2]][[2]]$questionlist, exm2[[2]][[2]]$questionlist)
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(exm1[[2]][[3]]$questionlist, exm2[[2]][[3]]$questionlist)
## [1] TRUE
```

Both have to be called separately, though, there is no option to produce both in one go, currently.